# Includes folder in a middleman app?

Tags: middleman

I inherited a repo for a middleman static pages repository and it has an `includes` folder and some odd markdown syntax in a file. The file is located here: `root/folder1/thing.index.md`:

```
---
title: some app

toc_footers:
  - © thing3

search: true

includes:

- orders/introduction
- orders/active/examples

- footer
---
```

and I have these files: `root/includes/orders/_introduction.md` and `root/includes/orders/active/_examples.md`.

What is this structure? I can't find this structure or syntax anywhere in the `middleman` project? Where is the `includes:` method coming from?

Answer (score 0):

These are examples of [Yaml Frontmatter](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/frontmatter/).

In this case `current_page.data.includes` will point to an array containing the two entries.
Then there should be code that does something with this `includes` variable e.g. iterate over it using something like `<% current_page.data.includes.each do |filename| %>`.

This code will either be in your repo or in some gem that you are including in your Middleman project (e.g. like this [one](https://github.com/lord/slate/wiki/Using-Includes)).